# не могу разобраться с Invoke()

Tags: c#, unity3d

я хочу чтобы когда я нажимал на кнопку "w"
объект начал перемещаться наверх по 10y в секунду
Я использовал Invoke а объект сразу телепортируется на 50 y
без задержки

```cs
    void goUp()
    {
        ts.position +=  new Vector3(0,10,0);
    }

    void posUp()
    {
        while(downOtherKey == false)
        {
            while(i <=5)
            {
                Invoke("goUp",1f);  
                i++;
            }
            downOtherKey = true;
        }
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
        {
            posUp();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Советую вместо `Update` использовать `FixedUpdate`. Стандартно он вызывается 50 раз в секунду, т.е. в `GoUp` поставьте `0.2` по y

И, совет. Не делайте передвижение через transform, если, конечно же, вы не хотите пренебречь законами физики. Для передвижения "*по-физике*" отлично подходит RigidBody и установление его velocity (скорости)

Comment: Спасибо , сейчас попробую 
Я понимаю что непрвильно использовать transfor.position 
Но я делаю змейку в 2д и мне нужно чтоби она перемещалась на 10 по оси раз там в пол секунду 
И я не знаю как єто зделать с физическим перемещением.